# Trouble: Apache httpd service does not start and no logs appears

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I'm starting a fresh installed instance of Apache 2.2.16 service under Windows Server 64 bit:

```
> net start apache2.2
The Apache2.2 service could not be started.
```

The same thing happens starting it from Services. Nothing has appeared under logs/. None change was introduced into configs.

Please advise **how to look at the logs** at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran in a smiliar problem on friday so you might want to run apache from terminal:

```
$ %PROGRAMFILES%\Apache Group\Apache2\bin\Apache.exe
```

or something analog to this should do the trick. If you have also PHP5 installed I ran into problems if the installation path contained special chars.

Comment: Thanks! Finally I got the error message running httpd.exe as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Windows administrator, but in the Apache installation path, you should have a directory named "log", look at error.log or something like.